# Не получается подключить расширение к yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii

Вот само расширение https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-taggable-behavior
Не могу понять эту документацию, только учусь

модель Article:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use app\models\ArticleFile;
use app\models\Category;
use app\models\Tag;
use app\components\ImgBehavior;
use dosamigos\taggable\Taggable;
use app\components\TagBehavior;
use yii\helpers\FileHelper;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "article".
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $title
 * @property string $desc
 * @property string $text
 * @property string $date
 * @property int $category_id
 * @property int $status
 *
 * @property Comment[] $comments
 */
class Article extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{


    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            [
                'class' => ImgBehavior::className(),
            ],
            [
                'class' => TagBehavior::className(),
            ],
            [
                'class' => Taggable::className(),
            ],
            'slug' => [
                'class' => 'Zelenin\yii\behaviors\Slug',
                'slugAttribute' => 'slug',
                'attribute' => 'title',
                // optional params
                'ensureUnique' => true,
                'replacement' => '-',
                'lowercase' => true,
                'immutable' => false,
                // If intl extension is enabled, see http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/general. 
                'transliterateOptions' => 'Russian-Latin/BGN; Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII; NFD; [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; NFC;'
            ]
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'article';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['desc', 'text', 'title', 'img', 'img_url'], 'required'],
            [['desc', 'text', 'slug'], 'string'],
            [['date', 'sup_hot', 'imageFile', 'slug', 'tagNames'], 'safe'],
            [['category_id', 'status'], 'integer'],
            [['title'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['slug'], 'unique', 'targetClass' => 'app\models\Article', 'targetAttribute' => 'slug'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'title' => 'Title',
            'slug' => 'Slug',
            'desc' => 'Desc',
            'text' => 'Text',
            'date' => 'Date',
            'category_id' => 'Category ID',
            'status' => 'Status',
        ];
    }

    public function upload($slug, $date)
    {

        $url = 'file/article/'.date("Y").'/'.date("m");

        FileHelper::createDirectory($url, $mode = 0775, $recursive = true);


        if ($this->validate()) {
            $this->imageFile->saveAs($url .'/'. md5($slug.$date). '.' . $this->imageFile->extension);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }



    public function newImage($id, $ext)
    {
        $url = '/2018/img/'.date("my").'/';

        $article = Article::find()
            ->where(['id' => $id])
            ->one();
        $article->img = $url.md5($article->slug.$article->date).'.'.$ext;

        if ($article->save()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }


    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getTags()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Tag::className(), ['id' => 'tag_id'])
            ->viaTable('tag_article', ['article_id' => 'id']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Category::className(), ['id' => 'category_id']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getTag()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Tag::className(), ['id' => 'tag_id'])->viaTable('tag_article', ['article_id' => 'id']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getComments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::className(), ['article_id' => 'id']);
    }

        /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getArticleFile()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ArticleFile::className(), ['article_id' => 'id']);
    }
}
```

Модель Tag:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "tag".
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $title
 *
 * @property ArticleTag[] $articleTags
 */
class Tag extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'tag';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['title'], 'required'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'title' => 'Title',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getArticleTags()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ArticleTag::className(), ['tag_id' => 'id']);
    }
}
```

Модель TagArticle

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "tag_article".
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property int $article_id
 * @property int $tag_id
 */
class TagArticle extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'tag_article';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['article_id', 'tag_id'], 'required'],
            [['article_id', 'tag_id'], 'integer'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'article_id' => 'Article ID',
            'tag_id' => 'Tag ID',
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: В чем проблема? 
`composer require 2amigos/yii2-taggable-behavior:~1.0` сделали?

Comment: @robertobadjo да, конечно. Видимость есть, все вроде верно, но ошибка `Class 'app\modules\team\controllers\Response' not found`

Comment: Ну это ошибка не в подключении расширения, а Ваша.  У Вас не найден класс `Response`.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было просто подключить `use yii\web\Response;`